# Asp.net MVC binding to view model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dnx

**Current Situation:** Starting with ASP.net MVC development and coming from MVVM app development I'm struggling with the binding of a view with view model / controller. I started with an empty project and tried to create model, viewmodel, controller and view. Starting the project I get a "500 Internal server error" but don't understand what's wrong (no error in the output window). I just can't understand how a view actually binds to a view model (probably because I think too much in MVVM).

**What I currently have:**

**Startup.cs:**

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseIISPlatformHandler();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Sample}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }

        // Entry point for the application.
        public static void Main(string[] args) => WebApplication.Run<Startup>(args);
    }
}
```

**Model:**

```
using System;

namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public class SomeModel
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using WebApplication1.Models;

namespace WebApplication1.ViewModels
{
    public class SampleViewModel
    {
        public IList<SomeModel> SomeModels { get; set; }

        public SampleViewModel()
        {
            SomeModels = new List<SomeModel>();
            SomeModels.Add(new SomeModel()
            {
                Time = DateTime.Now,
                Title = "Hallo"
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;
using WebApplication1.ViewModels;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class SampleController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Sample/
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(new SampleViewModel());
        }
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
@model WebApplication1.ViewModels.SampleViewModel

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hallo</title>
</head>
<body>
    @foreach (var someModel in Model.SomeModels)
    {
        <div>@someModel.Title</div>
    }
</body>
</html>
```

I found a lot of articles talking about model binding but they only talk about forms and input. What I want is to show some data, e.g. from a database in some kind of list or so and therefore don't need to post any date to the website.

Does anyone see the (probably obvious) issue in my sample code?

The project is based on **ASP.net 5 MVC 6** using **DNX**.

I already set some breakpoints to see whether the controller is actually called. And it is. I went through the few methods with the debugger without any issue. Also, the output window does not show any error or sth. like that.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code? Set a breakpoint at `Index()` and you should find where the error is happening. Perhaps you're not even hitting your controller

Comment: Its a very generic error. what you can try is to put some breakpoints (index method )and see whether it is getting fired. you can also check in developer tools(network) to check the url address. Also check the Routeconfig class method definition. These are the points i can think of now.

Comment: Show Startup. It could be a startup configuration issue. You haven't really given much detail as to the issue. 500 error could be anything. You started with an empty project, so there stands to reason that you may have left something out that was needed to run the app

Comment: looks like your problem somewhere in `IActionResult`. Your example [working well with ASP.NET MVC 4](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mc3tE7)

Comment: If you haven't done so already, it may help to set up error handling in your application to get more context as to why the 500 error is occurring. Check out this article for how to do that: http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/error-handling.html

Comment: As others have mentioned, please post your Startup.cs. I have an inclination that something may not be configured properly for MVC, though can't be sure until we see that code.

Comment: I used the debugger to go through the few methods that I have. The controller is called, the viewmodel is created, ... .

Comment: Anything in the Windows EventLog?

Comment: I can't find anything in the EventLog

Comment: Just found the cause for this. The view name was missing in the result for the GET method. So instead of `return View(new SampleViewModel());` it must be `return View("Sample", new SampleViewModel());`. I thought that the connection between view and controller is purely convention based. So a controller named `Sample` searches for a view named `Sample` in a folder called `Sample` which in turn is a subfolder of `Views`. Am I missing something? (I'm gonna update this question with the answer but would be thankful in case for a short explanation of this behavior)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view name was missing in the result for the GET method. So instead of

```
return View(new SampleViewModel());
```

it must be

```
return View("Sample", new SampleViewModel());
```

I thought that the connection between view and controller is purely convention based. So a controller named `Sample` searches for a view named `Sample` in a folder called `Sample` which in turn is a subfolder of `Views`.

Not sure exactly why, but it works this way.

Comment: MVC does, in fact, use convention to determine how to locate the correct view.  You were pretty close, actually, but what you missed is that the framework isn't just using the controller name, it's also using the action's name.  In your case, if you would've created a `~/Views/Sample/Index.cshtml` view, that would've been correctly located and rendered without the need to specify the view name in the `return` statement.  Notice that `Index.cshtml` corresponds with the `Index` action on your controller.